# Warning: ZipArchive::addFile(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object

Tags: magento2, php, php-7

I am trying to zip the files in a folder. Example: In a path *localhost/magento/var/log*, there are two files *system.log, debug.log*. Following is the code which I tried to zip the files. Am developing this in MAGENTO 2.  Am getting an error when adding a file to zipping.

```
$filePath = $this->_dir->getPath('log');//[/rootpath/var/log]
$logFileConfigurations = scandir($filePath, 1);//[system.log, debug.log]
if (is_array($logFileConfigurations)) {
    foreach ($logFileConfigurations as $configuration) {
        if ($dir = opendir($filePath)) {
            $file = $configuration;
            chdir($filePath);
            try {
                $zip = new ZipArchive();
                $fileName = $configuration . date("d-m-YH:i:s") . '.zip';
                $fileName = str_replace(" ", "", $fileName);

                if ($zip->open($fileName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === false) {
                    die ("An error occurred creating your ZIP file.");
                }

                $zip->addFile($file);
                $zip->close();
                unlink($file);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your zip file inside your loop.

Move `$zip->close();` out side foreach and check again.

I hope it will work.

Comment: The Issue was the special characters which I use from "date and time" when creating a file. I replaced all special characters like " -,: " with empty space using str_replace(). And it worked!!